# telerik report chart percentage

Tags: c#, visual-studio, telerik-reporting

how can i get similar result on Telerik Report with showing percentage instead of the Count value that is shown by default.

i'm using C# in my application.

thanks

[image]

Comment: I've been able to show the value not the percentage. i.e it shows 2 instead of 20% and 8 instead of 80%. i want to convert it to a percentage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it looks in my app

```
<telerik:PieSeriesDefinition AxisName="YourName"
                             ShowItemLabels="True"
                             ItemLabelFormat="#%{P0}" 
                             RadiusFactor="0.7">
```

The key here is the `ItemLabelFormat` with `RadiusFactor` you can move it as far as you want from the center

Forgot to add this to the answer as well. Inside `ChartDefaultView.ChartArea` add this

```
 <telerik:ChartArea.AxisY>
     <telerik:AxisY AxisName="YourName" DefaultLabelFormat="#VAL{p}"/>
 </telerik:ChartArea.AxisY>
```